# Angular few events on one button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

learning Angular, met another issue in my way, hope anyone can help.
I've got one button that must perform two actions: download something and send formdata to the server. So I've wrote this:

```
<form id='download'>
  <label for='name'>Name:</label>
  <input type='name' ng-model='nameValue'>
  <label for='email'>Email:</label>
  <input type='email' id='email' ng-model='emailValue'>
</form>

<a ng-click='sendFormDataIfVal()' href="{{filename}}" download="{{filename}}">Download</a>
```

But the problem and my question is - now downloading and sending occur simultaneously while I wanna download file only if *emailValue* pass validation and *nameValue* is not empty. Suppose it's gonna be something like this, but I dunno how to complete function

```
$scope.sendFormDataIfVal = function() {
  $scope.validateEmail() && $scope.sendFormData();  // download & send
  if(!$scope.validateEmail()) {
    // do not download and do not send
  }
};
```

Any advise will be greatly... u know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to disable the link using css.
once enabled, both the click event handler and the native download function will work.

toggle the link's 'disabled' css class via a validation function

here is a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/W3i20GZqqK5rIWGsFEdJ?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        <form id="download">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="name" ng-model="nameValue" />
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" ng-model="emailValue" />
        </form>
        <a ng-class="{'disabled' :  !isFormValid()}"  ng-click="sendFormData()" ng-href="{{fileUrl}}" download="{{fileName}}" >Download</a>
      </body>
```

**JS**

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.emailValue = 'sample@email.com';
      $scope.nameValue = ""; 
    $scope.fileUrl = "http://thatfunnyblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/funny-videos-funny-cats-funny-ca.jpg";
    $scope.fileName = "funny-cat.jpeg";


      $scope.isEmailValid = function(){
        //replace this simplified dummy code with actual validation
        return $scope.emailValue.indexOf('@') !== -1;

      }

      $scope.isFormValid = function(){

      return   $scope.isEmailValid() &&  $scope.nameValue.length;

      }

      $scope.sendFormData = function(){

        console.log('sent that data');

      }

    }]);
```

**CSS**

```
a.disabled{ 
/*simulate disabled using css, since this property is nto supported on anchor element*/
color:gray;
pointer-events:none;

}
```

Comment: glad to help :) happy coding

Comment: can I ask u one more question?)

Comment: sure, what do you need?

Comment: I need to activate all that logic only when my form in 'show' position. I mean I've got ng-click="show =! show" on my form and when it's showing it have to be validated if user wanna download file, but if form in 'hide' position it is not necessary to pass validation ( form actually is not visible at all ) and download button have to be just clickable. Hope I make myself clear

Comment: I can create separate question for that if you can help if you wish for one more acceptance :)

Comment: just update the logic in the isFromValid function   
  $scope.isFormValid = function(){
  
  return  !$scope.showFrom ||  ($scope.isEmailValid() &&  $scope.nameValue.length;)
    
  }  https://plnkr.co/edit/W3i20GZqqK5rIWGsFEdJ

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.sendFormDataIfVal = function() {    
  if(!$scope.validateEmail()) {
    // do not download and do not send
  }
else{
download and send
}
};
```